# is there a way to prevent duplication of entries in neDB collection's array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, embedded-database, nedb

```
var addNewUser = function (id, chatId) {
    db.update({ _id: id }, { $push: { users: chatId } }, {}, function (err, numAffected) {
        // code after the record is updated
    });
}
```

in this code
I want to push new Id to the array if it is not in it.

I've read the [docs](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#updating-documents) of neDB but it seems there is no way to do that

I'm beginner so I think there is a way to do that but I cant see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push new `chatId` to `users` array only if it does not exist, you can use `$addToSet`. According to the nedb [document](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#updating-documents):

> $addToSet adds an element to an array only if it isn't already in it

Here is the example code:

```
var addNewUser = function (id, chatId) {
  db.update({ _id: id }, { $addToSet: { users: chatId } }, {}, function (err, numAffected) {
    // code after the record is updated
  });
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't work for me. 
it keeps adding duplicate chat ids
* my chat ids are saved as numbers

Comment: What does the `chatId` look like? Can you provide an example?

Comment: "159263523" this is a chat id